# NHibernate, how solve the mapping with depending on a other column

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the table A like below:

```
Table A
-----------------------
Id
Desc
ReferenceType
TargetId
...
```

Depend on the value of reference type, eg 'B' or 'C', target ID reference to table B or table C.
Have anyone solve this problem with NHibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the mapping `<any>` have a look at this [blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/3966/nhibernate-mapping-any).
Or in this [Fabio Maulo Knol](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-5-basic-o-r-mapping#) look for ***5.2.4. Any type mappings***

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at discriminators I think. The following articles should help.

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/10/nhibernate-mapping-inheritance.aspx

http://ayende.com/blog/3941/nhibernate-mapping-inheritance